# An active underground city/village?

Tags: where-on-earth

I recently went on a tour of [Project Riese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Riese) and it got me wondering about whether there are actual active underground cities I could visit. Is there a place that's available not only for a tour, but where one could live for some time without coming back to the earth surface?

Comment: How long is "some time"?  Long enough to need underground grocery stores and medical facilities?

Comment: There is also an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_city) and a [category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Underground_cities) on Wikipedia related to this question.

Comment: @WGroleau "ideally, yes" for the groceries, "not necessarily" for medical facilities.

Answer (score 15):

You can join the [100k to 1M](https://www.mentalfloss.com/article/563950/why-1-million-people-live-underground-beijing) people living underground Beijing in a network of bunkers covering [around 85 km²](https://www.the-sun.com/news/1252606/inside-china-underground-city-dungeon-millions-live-rat-tunnels/) called [Dìxià Chéng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_City_(Beijing)), where you can sleep and eat:

[image: A man working in a kitchen]

[image: A hallway with clothes hanging to dry]

[image: A woman at a computer with a smiling little girl sitting in her lap, in a bedroom]

(Image sources: [DailyMail](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-8596711/Over-million-people-live-subterranean-tunnels-China.html) and [Medium](https://medium.com/@mrbradbailey/beijings-rat-tribe-a-million-migrants-living-underground-7ce904ef0b))

Follow-up question: [Where can I find a map of the Underground City (Beijing)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/171535/1810)

---

More ideas on Wikipedia:
[underground city](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_city) and [underground living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_living), but I think Dìxià Chéng is the most populated underground complex.

Comment: The government claimed the tunnels could house six million people, but that's only fourteen square meters per person if _all_ of the 85m² were living space.   I can sleep in a tent of three square meters, but to also cook and bathe and shop and …

Comment: @WGroleau, in many places 3 or more people will live on those 3 square meters, often no more than 3 cubic meters.  And having seen some video footage of small 'housing' in some Asian cities (one bed, not high enough to sit up in, storage over the foot) I can believe those numbers.

Answer (score 9):

Canada is known for its tunnel systems in many downtowns that let pedestrians avoid snow and ice above. For example, there is the [RÉSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_City,_Montreal) in Montreal and the  [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(Toronto)) in Toronto.

Comment: Meanwhile, in the West we went skywards. Calgary has [+15](https://www.calgary.ca/transportation/roads/road-maintenance/bridge-rehabilitation/plus15skywalk.html?redirect=/plus15) and Edmonton the [Pedway](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edmonton_Pedway). Regina also has a few skywalks.

Comment: Can one sleep underground in RÉSO or PATH?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt The Wikipedia articles count "*six major hotels*" as [facilities connected to PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(Toronto)#Connected_facilities), describe RÉSO as "*a series of interconnected […] hotels, [and] residential […] complexes*" and [list 9 hotels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underground_City,_Montreal#Hotels) there. I would assume that counts?

Comment: @Bergi thanks, I was wondering if these hotels offer underground rooms. In case someone really don't want to see the overground world :)

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Oh, that I don't know. Never been there myself.

Comment: I live in Montreal, and the "underground city" is a misnomer. Really it's an *indoor* city, and a bunch of it is underground like the Metro and pedestrian tunnels. Nobody actually lives underground.

Answer (score 6):

You might be interested in [Coober Pedy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coober_Pedy), South Australia.

> Coober Pedy is renowned for its below-ground dwellings, called "dugouts", which are built in this fashion due to the scorching daytime heat.

Comment: I've been there, and while the underground houses are cool (literally and figuratively), they're not connected to each other -- you still need to go outside to do anything.

Comment: Similar existed in Kansas in my great- great-grandfather's time (he built one and lived in it.  My father helped someone build one in Oklahoma.  The city waited until after it was finished to tell the owner he's not allowed to live in a house where the bedrooms don't have escape windows.